# getting UIWebview bigger with auto resize or auto layout

Tags: uiwebview, resize, autoresize, iphone-5, autolayout

I have 3 objects in a view - a label at the top - a uiwebview in the middle - a button at the bottom. I am trying this to work either with auto-resizing (the old way) or auto layout (the new way) but can't succeed.

I would like to obtain the label and button to stick at the top /bottom (staying the same size) - AND - would like the uiwebview to get bigger accordingly. So on iPhone 4 it is the maximum height for that screen - and on iphone 5 as well.

Is that as a start possible in this scenario or do I have to add another nib just like to do with universal apps?

Thanks for any help to start doing this

Cheers
geebee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pin the label to maintain its Height and its "Top Space to Superview".
Pin the button to maintain its Height and its "Bottom Space to Superview".
Then resize the web view to where you want it and Pin it to maintain both its "Top Space to Superview" and its "Bottom Space to Superview".

That should do it!

Comment: it did! Thanks a lot. for info, I also pin the webview to resize automatically.